# How to save a very large binary code in java

Tags: java, serialization, size, biginteger

I want to save a very large number like `111111111100000001010` in an ArrayList in java. After saving I should be able to find the number of bytes needed to save it.
The number is found using a function `String Find_code(int input)`. How can I efficiently save it in memory? For example  21 bits for `111111111100000001010`.

Comment: Why not to use BigInteger?

Comment: For above example the size will be 211 bytes I need 21 bit

Comment: Why would it be 211? Why (and how) do you need to store it in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: The “number of bytes needed to save it” is just the number of bits divided by eight. And the most efficient way to save a “very large number” having less than or exactly 32 Bits is an `int`— maybe just the `int` from which you got that value?

Comment: So for above expamle it will be 21/8 bytes not 211 bytes

Comment: @Holger: `The “number of bytes needed to save it” is just the number of bits divided by eight` -- Unless the data structure is using a 32 bit integer or 64 bit integer as a base type.

Comment: @Holger: A BitSet, for example (see my answer below).  Normally these things allocate bits in 32 or 64 bit increments; it's more efficient that way.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: that `BitSet` is part of your answer but not of the question. The question was how many bytes are *needed*. Surly you can always find solutions taking more bytes. It’s not even clear what “save it” means, maybe in a file?

Comment: @Holger Sorry for confusion I mean save in memory

Comment: @Holger: The Java documentation does not state what the storage requirements are for BitSet, only saying that it's implementation independent.  The best thing to do is try it and see how much memory it really uses.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: that’s not the point. The question does not imply that a `BitSet` is ever needed. *If* it is needed, it will of course consume more memory than a byte array or a plain `int`.

Comment: @holger: There's an answer space below these comments, where you can post your own solution.

Comment: @sweet: you should be more specific about the requirements in your question. Do you need a storage which can grow? Do you know the maximum number of bits you will need?

Comment: @Holger: Now you understand why I answered the way I did. :)

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I didn’t question your answer. But you did question my statement that the required number of bytes is bits/8. But my statement was not related to your answer.

Comment: @Holger: Generally, when you write code for a BitSet or BitArray type data structure, you use 32 bit or 64 bit integers, for efficiency reasons.  That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

> This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each
>   component of the bit set has a boolean value. Individual indexed bits
>   can be examined, set, or cleared.

Comment: So for String val = "111111111100000001010";
BitSet is {1, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

Comment: If by that representation you mean the bit positions that are set, then yes.

Comment: Thanks How should I save it in memeory?

Comment: It's a data structure.  You create a new instance, and store your bits in it.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If `111111111100000001010` is a binary number, then it will fit in an integer. Simply store it in an array list of integers `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: No it shows me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "111111111100000001010"

Comment: @sweet: Did you really use `Integer.parseInt(…, 2)`?

Comment: @sweet: more memory than *what*?

Comment: @sweet: Your question said that the binary number you want to store is *very large*.  Having a few extra bits in an integer shouldn't matter.